# Rails nested resource form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My project has users who can create activities and rate others' activities. I use an _activity partial in two views: one to list the users' own activities and one to list others' activities the user hasn't yet rated. In the latter case, I also include a form to rate that activity. It should submit to the ratings model with the current user's ID, the activity's ID and their rating. How can I get the activity id since their is no @activity variable, just an @activities collection which renders the partial for each member? Should I switch to an each method?

Here is my code so far:

for the user's own activity index:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = current_user
    @activities = @user.activities.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

for their page of others' activities to rate:

```
def not_rated
    @user = current_user
    @activities = Activity.not_rated(current_user).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order(created_at: :desc)
    @rating = Rating.new
end
```

The second of the two views that calls the partial (not_rated.html.erb):

```
<div class="rate_activities">
        <h3> Rate Activities! (<%= @activities.count %>)</h3>
        <% if @activities.any? %>
            <%= render @activities %>
            <%= will_paginate @activities %>
            <% end %>
    </div>
```

The _activity partial:

```
<ul class="activities" >
<li class="activity">
    <span class="content"><%= activity.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(activity.created_at) %> ago</span>
    <% unless activity.user_id == @user.id %>
        <%= form_for([@rating, activity]) :url => new_activity_rating_path do |f| %>
            <p><%= f.text_field :rating %></p>
            <%= f.submit "Submit my Activity", class: "mybutton" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

</li>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on your code in the _activity partial, you already have access to an `activity` variable so you don't need an instance var `@activity` in your index or not_rate actions. Your `render @activities` already calls your `_activity.html.erb` partial and it automatically makes a local variable `activity` available to the same partial.

About the activity_id, you can get it in your partial by doing `activity.id`. Something like:

`<%= f.hidden_field :id, value: activity.id %>`

Make sure to whitelist :id with either strong_parameters or protected_attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a local variable:

```
<%= render partial: 'activity', collection: @activities, locals: { activity: @activity } %>
```

Comment: I added the not_rated.html.erb view for clarification: it doesn't render the partial specifically, but renders @activities. Can I do the same thing here?

Comment: where `@activity` is `Activity.new`, I guess